# Como customizar "Notification Web API" no Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

Estou criando um navegador simples usando [**QtWebkit**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkit-index.html) e adicionei nele o "suporte" para [**Notification Web API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) usando o `QWebPage::setFeaturePermission`.

Um exemplo:

```
function notifyMe() {
    if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
    } else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
        Notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {
            if (permission === "granted") {
                var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
            }
        });
    }
}

<button onclick="notifyMe();">Notify me</button>
```

Código:

```
QObject::connect(page,
    SIGNAL(featurePermissionRequested(QWebFrame*, QWebPage::Feature)), this,
    SLOT(featurePermissionRequested(QWebFrame*,QWebPage::Feature))
);

...

void Form::featurePermissionRequested(QWebFrame* frame, QWebPage::Feature feature) {
    switch (feature) {
        case QWebPage::Notifications:
            qDebug() << "Notification";
            page->setFeaturePermission(frame, feature, QWebPage::PermissionGrantedByUser);
        break;
        case QWebPage::Geolocation:
            qDebug() << "GEO";
        break;
        default:
            qDebug() << "Unknown feature";
    }
}
```

Sempre que eu clico no botão "Notify me" aparece a seguinte mensagem no Desktop:

[image: Desktop Notification]

Ou seja funciona perfeitamente, porém gostaria de saber se é possível "customizar" as "notifications" no Qt?

Em outras palavras, gostaria que elas fossem similares ao do GoogleChrome ou Firefox, algo como isto:

[image: Web Notification]

Comment: mas você não pode customizar usando o JS mesmo? Vê lá na própria página da mozilla tem como customizar, icones, corpo, etc

Comment: @AdirKuhn Acho que você não entendeu o "customizar". O QWebPage usa o `QSystemTrayIcon` para gerar as notificações, o que eu quero é substituir o `QSystemTrayIcon` por um QWidget customizado. Pois mesmo que eu altere o icone no `Notification` ainda sim o QT usa o `QSystemTrayIcon` como na imagem: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oxiZT.png Eu **não** quero usar `QSystemTrayIcon`, quero que seja uma janela *bonitinha*, parecida com está: http://i.stack.imgur.com/S62wY.png

Comment: Conseguiu? Fiquei curioso, kkkkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para customizar o `Notifications Web API` no `QtWebkit` será necessário usar o "Webkit plugins", ou seja, criar um plugin e colocar no diretório `qtdir/plugins/webkit`.

> **Nota:** Para criar os plugins será necessário usar o "header" `<QtWebKit/QWebKitPlatformPlugin>`

### Criando um plugin Webkit:

- Crie um projeto no QtCreator
- No arquivo `.pro` (exemplo `src.pro`) adicione isto:

  ```
  TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget(meupluginwebkit)
  TEMPLATE = lib
  CONFIG += plugin

  HEADERS += $$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/QtWebKit/qwebkitplatformplugin.h \
      meupluginwebkit.h

  SOURCES += \
      meupluginwebkit.cpp

  DESTDIR = $$PWD/bin-plugin
  OBJECTS_DIR = $$PWD/build-plugin
  MOC_DIR = $$PWD/build-plugin
  RCC_DIR = $$PWD/build-plugin
  UI_DIR = $$PWD/build-plugin
  ```
- Crie o arquivo meupluginwebkit.h na pasta do projeto

  ```
  #ifndef MEUPLUGINWEBKIT_H
  #define MEUPLUGINWEBKIT_H

  #include <QtWebKit/QWebKitPlatformPlugin>

  class meupluginwebkit : public QObject, public QWebKitPlatformPlugin
  {
      Q_OBJECT
      Q_INTERFACES(QWebKitPlatformPlugin)

  #if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
      Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qtwebkit.QtWebKit.QtWebPlugin")
  #endif

  public:
      explicit meupluginwebkit();
      ~meupluginwebkit();

      bool supportsExtension(Extension ext) const;
      QObject* createExtension(Extension ext) const;
  };

  #endif // MEUPLUGINWEBKIT_H
  ```
- Crie o arquivo meupluginwebkit.cpp na pasta do projeto

  ```
  #include "meupluginwebkit.h"
  #include "notification/notification.h"

  meupluginwebkit::meupluginwebkit()
  {
  }

  meupluginwebkit::~meupluginwebkit()
  {
  }

  bool meupluginwebkit::supportsExtension(Extension ext) const
  {
      return ext == Notifications;
  }

  QObject* meupluginwebkit::createExtension(Extension ext) const
  {
      switch (ext) {
          case Notifications:
              return new Notification();

          default:
              return 0;
      }
  }

  //Para QT-4.8
  #if QT_VERSION < 0x050000
  Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(webkitplugin, meupluginwebkit);
  #endif
  ```
- Crie dentro da pasta do projeto uma pasta chamada `notification`
- Na pasta notification adicion adicione os arquivos:

  notification.h

  ```
  #ifndef NOTIFICATION_H
  #define NOTIFICATION_H

  #include <QtWebKit/QWebKitPlatformPlugin>

  class Notification : public QWebNotificationPresenter
  {
      Q_OBJECT

  public:
      explicit Notification();
      ~Notification();

      void showNotification(const QWebNotificationData* data);

  signals:
      void notificationClosed();
      void notificationClicked();
  };

  #endif // NOTIFICATION_H
  ```

  notification.cpp

  ```
  #include "notification.h"
  #include <QDebug>

  Notification::Notification() : QWebNotificationPresenter()
  {
      qDebug() << "Create: Notification";
  }

  Notification::~Notification()
  {
      qDebug() << "Delete: this (Notification)";
  }

  void Notification::showNotification(const QWebNotificationData* data)
  {
      qDebug() << "titulo:" << data->title();
      qDebug() << "icone:" << data->iconUrl();
      qDebug() << "mensagem:" << data->message();
      qDebug() << "pagina que chamou a notificação:" << data->openerPageUrl();
  }
  ```

No exemplo eu usei `qDebug` apenas para entendimento de como capturar os dados, para criar a sua notificação customizada, provavelmente você terá que usar `QWidget`

- Crie na pasta notification o arquivo `notification.pri`:

  ```
  QT += network

  HEADERS += \
      $$PWD/notification.h

  SOURCES += \
      $$PWD/notification.cpp
  ```
- Inclua o `notification.pri` no `src.pro`:

  ```
  include($$PWD/notification/notification.pri)
  ```

### Compilando o `src.pro`:

- Abra o projeto `src.pro` no QtCreator (se não estiver aberto)
- Clique no botão `Build` (o desenho do martelo, ou use Ctrl+B) - Nota: Não clique no botão "Run" (o desenho do botão "play" verde), não use Ctrl+R)
- Feche o projeto `src.pro`
- Abra a pasta aonde se encontra o arquivo `src.pro`
- Abra a pasta `bin-plugin`
- Copie o arquivo `meupluginwebkit.dll` para `QtDir/plugins/webkit/meupluginwebkit.dll` (exexemplo com mingw: `C:/qt/qt5.4/mingw/plugin/webkit/meupluginwebkit.dll`)
- Se a pasta webkit não existir, então crie ela.
- Abra o seu projeto que está usando `QWebView` e teste o JavaScript que usa `Notification Web API`.

Quando você rodar o projeto que usa o `QWebView`, ele automaticamente irá carregar a `dll` da pasta `webkit`, portanto não será necessário nenhum outro tipo de configuração e isto irá subistituir o sistema de notificação padrão do QtWebkit (que no caso no Windows usa o `SystemTrayIcon`) pelo seu `widget` customizado.