# Existe um modo de ver o código nativo de funções do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Recentemente percebi que existe um modo de reescrever o código nativo de certas funções em JavaScript. Por exemplo:

```js
console.log(confirm);

function confirm() {
  var a = "oi";
  return a;
}

var a = confirm();
console.log(a);
```

```js
console.log(confirm);
/*
function confirm() {
  var a = "oi";
  return a;
} 
*/
var a = confirm();
console.log(a);
```

Se perceber ao dar um `console.log` na função sem reescrevê-la aparece: `function confirm() { [native code] }`

**Existe algum modo de descobrir qual o código nativo de funções JavaScript?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em JavaScript puro **provavelmente não**, isso porque as funções nativas geralmente podem não estar escritas em JavaScript completamente, geralmente elas são **"interfaces"**, que são usadas para acessar uma funcionalidade interna do navegador ou prover funcionalidades para um outro recurso em um nível acima.

Este *[Como customizar "Notification Web API" no Qt?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52833/3635)* é um exemplo aonde usei *QtWebkit* (uma API que usa o motor *Webkit*) e tive que reescreve-la via C++ (API do Qt na verdade) para poder customizar as notificações Desktop.

Um exemplo, ainda falando de Qt, o webkit é possivel escrever as suas próprias funções, com `QWebFrame::addToJavaScriptWindowObject`:

```
void Exemplo::setWebView( QWebView *view )
{
    QWebPage *page = view->page();
    frame = page->mainFrame();

    define();
    QObject::connect( frame, SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()), this, SLOT(define()) );
}

void Exemplo::define()
{
    frame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject( QString("Exemplo"), this );
}
```

Claro que a pergunta nada tem haver com *Qt*, mas o que quero explicar é que desta maneira acima eu escrevi um objeto assim:

```
window.Exemplo.foo();
```

O qual me permitirá acessar funções da minha implementação em C++.

Ou seja não tem como visualizar o código nativo, pois provavelmente ele é apenas uma interface (na maior parte dos casos/navegadores), claro que pode haver alguma exceção, mas vai ser um ou outro.

Então realmente não há muito motivo para ler o código-fonte via JavaScript, isso porque "não existe" código JavaScript ali, essas funções nativas provavelmente só fazem a comunicação com a API do navegador/motor e isso dispara uma funcionalidade existente do navegador.

---

Agora se você quer apenas descobrir, independente de JavaScript, você terá que ler o código fonte do motor usado pelo navegador (webkit, Gecko, presto, blink, trident, etc) e dos navegadores também (chromium, firefox, msedge) em suas "versões" não compiladas, o que provavelmente são escritos em `C` ou `C++`

### Blink

Blink é a fork do Webkit, usado pelo Chrome e também é usado em outros navegadores, como [Opera](http://www.opera.com), [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com), etc.

- [LocalDOMWindow.h](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/frame/LocalDOMWindow.h?q=confirm%20lang:%5Ec%2B%2B$&sq=package:chromium&dr=CSs&l=134)
- [LocalDOMWindow.cpp](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/frame/LocalDOMWindow.cpp?q=confirm+lang:%5Ec%2B%2B$&sq=package:chromium&dr=CSs&l=777)

Que estendem deste ([*linha 33*](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/frame/LocalDOMWindow.h?l=33)):

- [DOMWindow.h](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/frame/DOMWindow.h?q=confirm%20lang:%5Ec%2B%2B$&sq=package:chromium&dr=CSs&l=154)

### Gecko

Gecko é o "motor" usado pelo [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) o outros produtos da Mozilla, como [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/), eu não estou certo deste ser o repositório apropriado, mas parece que o código que procura seja este:

- [nsGlobalWindow.h](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/e12cc94275050d3ecf1f5c4b0cbdf1846bec4891/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.h#L937)
- [nsGlobalWindow.cpp](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/e12cc94275050d3ecf1f5c4b0cbdf1846bec4891/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.cpp#L7033)

Answer (score 2):

Depende da implementação. Se ela tiver o código fonte disponível você consegue achar com algum esforço.

Se for o V8 que é usado pelo Chrome e um monte de produto, entre eles o Node.js, pode verificar no [GitHub do V8](https://github.com/v8/v8). Só não me peça para achar para você :) Talvez alguém que familiaridade com essa base de código possa dizer onde está. Em uma buscar rápida não achei.

Comment: Encontrei esse repositório: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/6a7ec6a3bf779cdd41c66a768fd7a37195ed7b7f/src/js/
Mas ainda me parece achar uma agulha no palheiro