# Como exatamente um programa é executado pelo navegador?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, navegador-de-internet, runtime

Não compreendi exatamente a diferença de um determinado código ser compilado pelo navegador ou pela máquina, visto que ambos (navegador e terminal) estão sendo executados na memória local.

Para sintetizar:

- Caso esta execução, de fato não aconteça na minha máquina, onde acontece?
- A partir de que momento o código não é mais executado pela minha máquina?
- Por que a execução dentro de um navegador, apesar do maior consumo de RAM, ocorre de ser mais rápida?

Agradeço também caso seja possível citar uma boa fonte de leitura e explicação.

Comment: JavaScript não é compilado, a verdade ele é interpretado. Quando diz que a execução do programa ocorre de ser mais rápida, você entende como mais rápida com relação a quê?

Comment: Quando vc diz "código compilado pelo navegador", está falando do JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é simples responder a pergunta principal para quem não tem uma base de programação muito forte, teria que quase escrever um livro ou recomendar antes a leitura de vários para que a resposta seja compreensível, é algo bastante avançado. Dá para tentar responder as secundárias em parte.

Não existe isso de "código ser compilado pelo navegador ou pela máquina", o código é compilado através de um software compilador e executado pela máquina, sempre, pode ter algum intermediário.

O compilador pode ser algo que só o programador tem acesso ou estar na máquina do usuário final que executará o programa. Isso ocorre quando o código na verdade é [interpretado de alguma forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190209/101), embora possa ser compilado à seguir.

## Compilação X interpretação

Essa coisa de [compilado ou interpretado é muito complicada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101). Um navegador costuma interpretar um código que vem para ele, tipicamente JavaScript, mas pode não ser, pode ser [WebAssembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101), que já foi previamente compilado de outra linguagem. Na verdade até o JS já pode ser resultado de uma [compilação prévia de outras linguagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/101) como [TypeScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101) por exemplo em um processo de [transpilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102787/101). Então é tudo mais complexo do que pode parecer.

De fato hoje todas implementações decentes nos navegadores possuem um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) que pega um código fonte, por isso parece interpretado, e compila para um [código nativo que será executado pela máquina](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179095/101), da mesma forma como se tivesse compilado previamente.

De fato no passado as implementações mais ingênuas que ainda existem, quem executava era o navegador, ou mais precisamente, uma parte dele, porque existia uma coisa chamada [máquina virtual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/332789/101). Boa parte das linguagens, especialmente de *script*, usam exatamente esse mecanismo, e ele pega o código fonte (JS é assim) ou um [*bytecode*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101) gerado (WebAssembly é assim) e executa o que precisa em um laço simulando o que uma máquina faria. Em última análise a execução ocorre na máquina, mas através de um software que controla isso. Poderia ser um que esteja dentro do navegador, mas não é o navegador.

Com o JITter não, o código [nativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458760/101) gerado é executado de forma direta.

Pode haver alguma forma híbrida em alguns casos, novamente, é mais complexo do que é visto por cima. Assim é a engenharia, veja como um motor é complexo, mas você não precisa entender de nada disso, até mesmo para consertar um hoje pode ser feito sem saber de nada, só com o equipamento certo.

## Velocidade e memória

A execução é rápida porque é um código nativo sendo executado, depois que passa pelo JITter. Por isso tem um custo inicial que não deixa inicial tão rápido, mas um humano nem percebe, ainda mais que a carga da página é extremante lenta proporcionalmente. Mas nem é tão rápido assim, principalmente em JS que é uma linguagem cheio de mecanismos abstratos que tem um custo alto. De qualquer forma não sei sobre o que está falando de ser mais rápida porque nem tem descrito com o que está comparando, ou mesmo se isso é verdadeiro, geralmente não é, a não ser que esteja falando de algo que executa de forma interpretada pura.

O consumo de RAM se dá justamente porque tem o código representado de mais de uma forma, mas geralmente isso é até pouco relevante, tem outras ineficiências muito mais graves por causa da características da linguagem, como por exemplo o [*garbage collector*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255769/101) e a [dinamicidade da tipagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324630/101).

## Navegador X terminal

A única semelhança entre navegador e terminal é que ambos são os softwares aparentes que o usuário vê para chamar um código, não são eles que executam o código, exceto por circunstâncias específicas, e mesmo assim é sempre por algum módulo diferente, ainda que no mesmo executável. Não misture o conceito de software usado para chamar/ver o resultado e o que compila e/ou executa.

Na prática o mesmo código pode ser executado de formas muito semelhantes em ambos, e de fato isto ocorre, já que é possível usar o [Deno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/444449/101) ou [Node](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157034/101) para executar código TypeScript/JavaScript pelo terminal ou outras formas de chamá-lo.

Se não respondi algo é porque não dá para saber o que deseja, é muito complicado fazer perguntas compreensíveis quando não se sabe a base do assunto e aí usa-se premissas falsas ou inconsistentes.

Veja mais em:

- [Diferença entre compilação Ahead-Of-Time e Just-in-Time](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356739/101)
- [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101)
- [Como um computador entende o código binário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado pela resposta, de verdade. Tenho lido os artigos e links que você anexou, e acompanhado links destas outras páginas consecutivamente. Bom, queria saber se você teria uma boa recomendação de livro ou artigo mais "universal" sobre os princípios da programação de computadores que um bom desenvolvedor deveria conhecer, algo pra ter uma boa base no que seria compilação e a interação do código com a máquina. É... de preferência algo escrito da forma mais simples que conseguir lembrar, porque eu sou meio lento, kkkk

Comment: Eu não gosto muito de indicar algo porque nem tudo é bom, o que eu conheço mais talvez esteja um pouco ultrapassado. Eu estou tentando ver se faço algo e posto aqui no site junto com outras pessoas porque isso é uma demanda de muitos. Mas vai pesquisando no site que tem muita informação de forma simples. As respostas mais votadas costumam ser bons começos.